# Using solder to extend RTD cable?

Tags: sensor, soldering, temperature, cables, rtd

I have a 3 wire RTD sensor (Pt100). The leads coming off of it are not long enough to reach our temperature controller. I bought some RTD extension cable (3 wire) from the same company.

Is it okay to use solder to connect the 3 wire RTD extension cable to the 3 leads on the RTD sensor? Or is this poor practice and would it meaningfully affect the temperature measurement accuracy? The other option would be to make sure I place 3 pin RTD connectors on either side of the cables instead of just soldering.

For our purposes we only need +-1 C in accuracy (and the RTD's are Class A) so I highly doubt this would make a difference, but thought I would ask and confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no problem with soldering to splice the wires. Just avoid adding mismatched length (a few cm won't matter) and match up the colors so the lead resistances are reasonably well matched.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it would be a problem, at least not in the way it would with thermocouple. A quick test would be to take a measurement before and after to see if the effects are suitable for your application.